# Best practices to maintain containers updated to the latest version in ECS with reliability

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, keycloak, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to self host a Keycloak instance as a container in ECS and I'm wondering what are the best practices for keeping it up to date with the latest patches (which, as you can imagine, is very important in a security sensitive topic like IAM).

The container needs to be reliable, an automatic update cannot make the system error out and leave the service in a down state because it is very critical. Ideally there should be a state where the automatic update is applied while the production system is still untouched, and have a manual step to let it update the real system (after some testing in the "staging" deployment of the update).

My idea is to have the IaC code in a repository with the container tag set to 'latest', and run a pipeline on a schedule to re-execute deployments so that the latest tags are applied. Is this the right approach? How do I deal with the reliability issue in ECS?

Thanks.